# springframework MockRestServiceServer fails in repetation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

I am using `org.springframework.test.web.client.MockRestServiceServer` to verify whether my client is working.

In the test I do the following:

```
            MockRestServiceServer mockRestServiceServer = MockRestServiceServer.bindTo(restTemplate).build();

            mockRestServiceServer
                    .expect(requestTo(basePath + "/processdataset"))
                    .andExpect(method(org.springframework.http.HttpMethod.POST))
                    .andExpect(content().contentTypeCompatibleWith(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA))
                    .andExpect(content().string(containsString("form-data; name=\"rulesetFile\"; filename=\"" + rulesetName + ".yml\"")))
                    .andExpect(content().string(containsString("form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"" + fileNameForInputData + "\"")))
                    .andExpect(content().string(containsString(expectedBody)))
                    .andExpect(content().string(containsString(expectedRulesetBody)))
                    .andRespond(withSuccess(expectedOutput, org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM))
            ;

            api.processDatasetFileToFile(rulesetFile, inputDataFile, new File("src/test/resources/testdatafiles/" + fileName + extension));

            mockRestServiceServer.verify();

            mockRestServiceServer.reset();
```

The test works fine if I run it a single time.

If I however anotate my unit test with `@RepeatedTest(5000)`, the test starts failing randomly.

It seems like not all the expectations are added to the mockRestServiceServer. When I run the test it says it only expects 'a string containing' the `expectedbody`(see the example above). However, since the request contains the expectedbody, the expectedRulesetBody, the necessary file name, etc (as it should), the test fails.

Again, most of the test work but about 1/8 unit test fail.

Thx in advance!